# Does Amazon Need to provide source for Silk?

Tags: licensing

I was looking at the traffic on my website, and saw some of that from the Amazon silk browser, which shows up as:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900R4 Build/LRX21T)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile
>   Safari/537.36

aside from clearly having some sort of identity crisis, the silk browser claims to be a Mozilla product.

The Mozilla license states that source code must be made available.
https://tldrlegal.com/license/mozilla-public-license-2.0-%28mpl-2%29

So I went to the Amazon silk site, and some Amazon sites, but I see no links, or references to download the source. So either Amazon is violating the license by not providing source code, or masquerading as an alternate browser, which (as I understand it) is illegal, under the terms of hacking, and e-crime.

Beyond that, I see no way to contact Amazon about this. What should someone do?

Comment: Not really a licensing issue: Even logs on my server shows things like that. I get `Mozilla/5.0` when requesting from Safari on a Mac. And the MPL doesn't force source code to be available: it runs on file-level copyleft, so only changes that you make to the files have to be made available if you distribute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version field of the [HTTP 'user-agent'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header is used to communicate compatibility level, not the provenance of the source code. Almost every browser around claims compatibility with Mozilla. In fact [Silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Silk) is based on the BSD licensed [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) browser, which doesn't impose a requirement on source distribution.

Comment: In case anyone wants to know why every browser says it's Mozilla: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1114297/4479896